# talend how can we estimate taggregateSortedRow recordcount parameter value

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

We are trying out talend  and we wanted to aggregate some sorted data on few keys .
Simple enough but when we try to use taggregatesortedrow its asking for Exact number of rows to be specified. 
I am not sure how any one can input this on the fly. Dosen't this value change for every run ? am i missing something. surely they cant expect us to know total recs before we run the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the way in how the Talend component tAggregateSortedRow is programmed. To avoid it omitting data you need to provide the record count. There are a few users with the same question like you asked:

- https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=50094
- https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=54231
- https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=7641

which I found simply by using Google.

Anyway, if you need to do sorting and aggregating, consider using the components tAggregateRow and tSortedRow separately. It should work fine.

Comment: personally i think it should be smart enough to detect key change event in rollup components but as long as we can use sort and aggregate in another component that solution works too thanks

Comment: "It is what it is says the Talend". If this or another answer helped you, consider upvoting and/ or accepting it.